# A word that means 'everything lined up perfectly'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means everything went just right, or lined up perfectly. I mean this more in the sense of 'happened very efficiently,' such as an assembly line (be it in a factory, kitchen, etc) that is well timed, well thought out, and effective. Could even be used to describe a well staged dance number.

Is there a word for this particular thing? Also, Synergy is not the word I'm looking for. Tech startups have ruined that word for me. :(

Answer (score 3):

Single word:

**groove**, noun \ˈgrüv\ -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groove)

2. a state in which you are able to do something well and easily especially because you are doing it often

---

Idioms:

**like clockwork** -[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+clockwork)

2. without problems. *Most of the performance went like clockwork, but there were a few little things that weren't perfect.*

**well-oiled machine** -[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/well-oiled)

1. a well-oiled system, project, or company operates without problems. Each of these can also be referred to as a well-oiled machine.

> Running like a well-oiled machine; everyone in their groove, the performance went like clockwork.

Comment: See also, [*without a hitch*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/without+a+hitch)

Answer (score 3):

*Well-choreographed* could work for your purposes.

A definition of [*choreograph*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/choreograph) from FreeDictionary.com:

> To plan out or oversee the movement, development, or details of; orchestrate: *aides who choreographed the candidate's tour.*

*Well-choreographed* implies that the work/event/process was planned carefully and even rehearsed, and then it went according to plan.

The term can, of course, be used for a well-staged dance number. But here are a couple of non-stage-related examples from [Wordnik:](https://www.wordnik.com/words/well-choreographed)

> *Saleh's speech Thursday was broadcast live on Yemeni television and included scenes of well-choreographed support.*
>
> *The IPO is well-choreographed to succeed, with a high-profile company with top-notch assets run by a successful executive.*

Answer (score 1):

*Flawless* and *seamless* are similar terms, but I'd imagine you'd need an action, like *flawless execution*.

If you wanted to get really archaic, you could say [ne plus ultra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_plus_ultra):

> **ne plus ultra** (n):
>
> 1. the highest, ultimate point of achievement which can be reached; perfection
> 2. the highest possible state, degree, or condition of quality; nothing better

Comment: I like ne plus ultra (I hadn't even heard it before now) but I don't think it fits what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

> **[precision](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/precision)**
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. The quality, condition, or fact of being exact and accurate

Answer (score 1):

While I can't think of a single word to fit your description, if you'll allow hyphenated constructions **perfectly-synchronized** or **perfectly-coordinated** might serve. In one word **synchronicity**

Answer (score 1):

Try "jibe".  Some people who don't hear too well substitute "jive" when attempting to communicate this idea.

> **jibe**<sup>2</sup>
>
> [no object] *North American informal*
>   Be in accord; agree:
>   *the verdict does not jibe with the medical evidence*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/jibe#jibe-2)

Answer (score 1):

**Streamlined** ... :) well organized and independently spontaneous.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try *meshed*. Everything just meshed and the planets aligned.

> To fit together effectively; be coordinated. ([American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mesh))

Answer (score 1):

I can't expect things to go better than **smoothly**.

***Smoothly*** is about as problem free as any organism could reasonably want or expect things to be under any circumstances. It's unpretentious yet strong. While it doesn't come with all the whistles and bells of other words, it leaves them behind *smoothly* in a couple of syllables.

Answer (score 0):

The business strategy in which maximum efficiency is reached by making sure everything is "perfectly timed" during the production process, so that the expense of holding surplus in-process inventory is minimised, is **[Just-In-Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_in_time_%28business%29)**. This is frequently abbreviated to **JIT**.

Comment: Is there an explanation for the downvote? The question did ask in the context of a production line.

Answer (score 0):

***sorted***

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sorted):

> Organized, arranged, or dealt with satisfactorily:
>
> ‘And your social
> commitments?’ ‘They’re well sorted’
>
> he’s working on that old car he’s
> been trying to get sorted
>
> The damp-proofing's
> almost all shot through, and we arranged to get this all sorted way
> back in the spring of 2001.
>
> We could have waited forever to try to get
> the cash absolutely right, but finally we decided to get going, even
> though the money side was far from sorted.
>
> I'll be hosted at that most
> excellent and free site for now, until I get some space of my own
> sorted.

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sorted):

> used to describe a situation in which everything is correctly
> organized or repaired, or when someone has everything that is needed:
>
> Debbie's sorted for Tuesday night because she's found a babysitter.
>
> "Have you spoken to Grant about the party?" "Sorted!"

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but the phrase [fall into place](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fall-into-place) means that events occurred smoothly and without errors to produce a desirable outcome.

It can suggest that the outcome is unexpectedly good, rather than the expected result, so it may not be the best way to describe the results of serious hard work.

"Although the rehearsal was a disaster, at the actual wedding, everything fell into place, and the ceremony went off without a hitch." (Or possibly WITH a hitch, in this particular case.)