# Is Miracle An Antonym of Catastrophe?

Tags: antonyms

In [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/596025/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-positive-antonym-to-catastrophe?newreg=c9d09d65649846ee92668fe8dda26931) that I do not have sufficient reputation to comment on,  @hyderallie28475 asks for antonyms of catastrophe, which they define as follows:

> A word for a positive event with far reaching positive
> consequences/benefits for many groups of people/targets, not just a
> select few. This event should be large in scope/effect, and the
> consequences needn't be sudden, as in the case of "catastrophe". The
> word should also be active/"violent" in mood/nature, not passive, like
> "boon", "fortune", or "phenomenon." It must be extreme.
>
> An example:
>
> The once-in-a-million-years meteor, rich in rare minerals, was a
> (positive antonym to catastrophe) for the FooBar Mining Colony;
> inspiring long lasting changes in their governance, economy, and
> society."

A few excellent answers were posited, such as the very uncommon word Eucatastrophy coined by Tolkien. I was curious if the word Miracle might also apply, which has the following definition:

> mir·a·cle /ˈmirək(ə)l/ noun
>
> 1. a surprising and welcome event that is not explicable by natural or scientific laws and
>    is therefore considered to be the work of a divine agency. "the
>    miracle of rising from the grave"
> 2. a highly improbable or extraordinary event, development, or accomplishment that brings very welcome consequences.
>    "it was a miracle that more people hadn't been killed or injured"
> 3. an amazing product or achievement, or an outstanding example of
>    something. "a machine which was a miracle of design"][2](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A%20miracle&source=hp&ei=lgw7Y-LMB8SG0PEPsIqMiAM&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYzsapov2b4RAfbt9unMWotgXOsQc7M13&ved=0ahUKEwji77amvMT6AhVEAzQIHTAFAzEQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=define%3A%20miracle&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyDQgAEIAEELEDEEYQ-QEyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBwgAEIAEEAoyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoICC4QsQMQgwE6CAgAELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoUCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QMQ1AI6CwguELEDEIMBENQCOg4ILhCABBDHARDRAxDUAjoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CAgAEIAEELEDOggILhCABBCxAzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6DgguEIAEELEDEIMBENQCOg0IABCxAxCDARBGEPkBOhAIABCABBCxAxCDARBGEPkBUABYyQxguw1oAHAAeACAAfEBiAHwEpIBBjAuMTEuM5gBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)

I'm reminded of the resurrection of Christ - which I think Tolkien listed as the prime example of eucatastrophe. A sudden event that we Christians believe had wide reaching positive consequences not just for Christ but for all of humanity.

Beyond the resurrection of Christ, there are ample examples of miracles throughout the historical record. Is miracle a potential answer to @hyderallie28475's request?

Comment: If you're intending this as an answer, you should post it as an answer to the question.

Comment: There is a movie in which Robert Redford, a cub reporter on a provincial newspaper, is advised by his editor to write a headline about an approaching severe storm, like ***Catastrophe Inevitable as Storm Approaches.*** Redford asks what they do if the storm misses the town. "You print ***Town Saved by Miracle***".

Comment: *Miracle*, taken literally, implies that the event is supernatural, while *catastrophe* doesn't (the last two of the three senses of *miracle* are best thought of as metaphorical).